# E:Line 1 too long in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list

Tags: updates

Ubuntu keeps telling me there is a system error and won't send updater to updates site.  this line keeps comming up:

```
E:Line 1 too long in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Post the content of that file. Open terminal and type as follows *cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list*

Comment: Actually, the Medibuntu repository is gone a very long time ago... What is your Ubuntu release? The only supported releases are: 12.04 (until April 2017 only), 14.04, 16.04 and the current 16.10. Any other is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I tried removing the `medibuntu` list by doing

> sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list

and now I can get updates  again.